# How to move a value in a slice to the last position in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice, move

I was wondering on how to properly move a slice element to the last position of a slice in Golang.

e.g:

```golang
func main() {
    slc := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
    fmt.Println(shiftEnd(slc,2))
}

func shiftEnd(s []int, x int) []int {
return append(s[x:],s[:x]...)
}
```

This will result in `[3,4,5,1,2`] I was wondering how to receive `[1,3,4,5,2]`.
So the received value, will be moved to the end, but the others will be kept in the same order.

[Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/X5j87CqGYnb)

Answer (score 2):

Here you are, the versoin with generics. Can handle the slice of any type.

```
// Relocates element at s[x] to the end ov the slice.
// Modifies `s` in place
func shiftEnd[T any](s []T, x int) []T {
    if x < 0 {
        return s
    }
    if x >= len(s)-1 {
        return s
    }
    tmp := s[x]
    // No allocation since the new slice fits capacity
    s = append(s[:x], s[x+1:]...)
    // append to the end
    // no allocation, the new slice fits the capacity
    s = append(s, tmp)
    return s
}
```

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/J7TmafgNwm3

```
func main() {
    test := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    fmt.Printf("before: %#v\n", test)
    out := shiftEnd(test, 2)
    fmt.Printf("after: %#v\nresult:  %#v\n", test, out)
}
```

Output:

```
before: []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
after:  []int{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3}
result: []int{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with this snippet solution, seems to work for what I was looking for.

```golang
func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Println(shiftEnd(s, 2))

}

func shiftEnd(s []int, x int) []int {
    if len(s) < 1 {
        fmt.Println("No Enought Values")
        return s
    }

    if s[len(s)-1] == x {
        fmt.Println("Already in the end")
        return s
    }
    return append(append(s[:x-1], s[x:]...), x)
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/QVBluosasRF)

Answer (score 0):

See commentary for details:

```
func shiftEnd(s []int, x int) []int {
    if len(s) <= 1 {
        return s
    }
    t := s[x]            // save value to move
    copy(s[x:], s[x+1:]) // shift elements down
    s[len(s)-1] = t      // set value at end
    return s
}
```

Use type parameters to write a function that works with any slice type:

```
func shiftEnd[S ~[]E, E any](s S, x int) S {
    if len(s) <= 1 {
        return s
    }
    t := s[x]            // save value to move
    copy(s[x:], s[x+1:]) // shift elements down
    s[len(s)-1] = t      // set value at end
    return s
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/CSWP6_4e0Ys

I am little confused about what OP is asking because OP's answer uses x as both an element value and an element index. This answer assumes that OP intended to use x as an index only.

Comment: The idea is move just the value, so if I don't know the index position I can just match a value and move it. The `x` could be interpreted as the word index, but actually I used in the meaning of an unknown value